# Get property that extends interface

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic function in TypeScript that returns the property of an object with the additional constraint that the returned property extends an `HasID` interface.

I would hope to be able to use it something like this:

```
let obj = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: {
    id: 123
  }
};

get(obj, 'foo') // Error
get(obj, 'bar') // Everything is fine
```

This is what I have so far:

```
interface HasID {
  id: number;
}

interface HasPropertyWithID<K, T extends HasID> {
  K: T
}

function get<
  T extends HasID, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  O extends HasPropertyWithID<K, T>
>(obj: O, key: K): T {
  return obj[key]
}
```

But it gives the error `'O[K]' is not assignable to type 'T'`. Is there some way to bend TypeScript's type system to support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a mapped type will constrain the value appropriately:

```
function get<
    K extends keyof O,
    T extends HasID,
    O extends { [P in K]: T }
    >(obj: O, key: K): T {
    return obj[key]
}
// Usage
let obj = {
    foo: 123,
    bar: {
        id: 123,
        ss: ''
    }
};

get(obj, 'foo') // Error
get(obj, 'bar') // Everything is fine
```